# Make python executable for both Windows and Mac (with dependencies)

Tags: python-3.x

I want to share my python script with someone who doesn't know what Python. That's why I want to make it to an executable (preferably for Mac and Windows but Windows is a priority).

I tried using pyinstaller and cx_freeze but they don't actually import the json file I need to run oauth2.

The traceback I get when I run the `.exe` is:

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "MyScrip.py", line 9, in  File "site-packages\oauth2client\service_account.py", line 219, in from_json_keyfile_name FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'creds.json' [11208] Failed to execute script MyScript

Anyone know how to do this? I tried Googling and looking for a solution but I am lost.

Thanks!

Comment: `pyinstaller` *does* work. So there is probably something funky in your code. Can you try to boil down your problem to a minimal reproducible example so that us on stackoverflow know what's going on?

Comment: Yes it does compile everything but it shows this error whenever I run the .exe 


As I've said, it doesn't seem to import the .json file
```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "MyScrip.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "site-packages\oauth2client\service_account.py", line 219, in from_json_keyfile_name
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'creds.json'
[11208] Failed to execute script MyScript```

Comment: And it doesn't throw that when you run the `.py` file? I would hazard a guess that you're using a relative path to `creds.json`. Is it possible for you to use an absolute path? Where is `creds.json` relative to the `.exe`?

Comment: @SyntaxVoidsupportsMonica, it's in the root folder where the MyScript.py is. 

For the code in line 9:


`credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('creds.json',scope)`

Comment: If you just pass the path `creds.json`, then the `.exe` will only look in the directory containing it. Can you copy/move `creds.json` so that it's in the same folder as the exe and try again?

Comment: In `pyinstaller`, in the call to `Analysis`, there is an argument `datas` in which you are supposed to list non-Python files that need to be packaged with the installation.  If you're not using that, or not using it correctly, then `creds.json` may not be getting included. Then, once you're sure it is getting included, you need to ensure that it is in the expected place relative to the *working directory* of the binary.  The best approach may be to piece together the absolute path to `creds.json` starting at the code's own `__file__` location (luckily, pyinstaller supports `__file__`).

Comment: Worked!! Thanks @SyntaxVoidsupportsMonica

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reposting the my comment-answer as an answer-answer.

The reason your `exe` was having a hard time finding the json file was because the use of relative paths instead of absolute paths. When the `exe` is compiled with `pyinstaller`, it's placed in a separate folder and any file-dependencies are not copied over.

The "quick" solution is to move the `json` into the same directory as the `.exe` but this can be troublesome if you compile frequently since you have to remember it everytime.

Instead of having to remember every time, you can write a `.bat` file that fully compiles your program with `pyinstaller` and moves all dependencies into the same directory as the `.exe`. The syntax is a bit different for every operating system.

Your script on Windows could look like this:

```
pyinstaller MyScript.py  # add any pyinstaller options you need
xcopy creds.json dist\main\creds.json
```

An automated "build" script is definitely beneficial when builds become more complicated.